# Variable not passing between functions

Tags: php

Here's what I have:

In file containging functions:

```
global $numTrax;
```

then I call a function within html page which is simply html for the player, but, at that point i want to put in how many tracks it plays so:

```
audioPlayer(5);
```

and the function is

```
function audioPlayer($numTrax)
{
    echo ' ... all html ...';

    // if i echo $numtrax here it shows 5
    // because function i used was audioPlayer(5)
    // so, i'm reassigning it using $numTrax = $numTrax
    // then next function: audioPlaylist($user_id,$username,$numTrax); has $numTrax
    // but the problem is it's not showing it there

    $numTrax = $numTrax;
    return $numTrax;
}
```

then I have another function further down the page which creates the track list and is called as follows:

```
audioPlaylist($user_id,$username,$numTrax);
```

The problem is that `$numTrax` is not being carried through

**QUESTION** Can I make the variable `$numTrax` travel through the functions?

Comment: Just declaring `global` once somewhere does not mean that variable is available in all functions! Are you passing the variable around somehow? Or are you just relying on your one `global` statement to make it pass magically?

Comment: 1. Don't use `global`.  Ever.  It's a crutch, and a dangerous one at that.

2. Can you show how you attempt to invoke the function?  Does `$numTrax` exist at that point?

Comment: Eh? Please read the question, I thought it was clear, if not please say how not so - oh, and I don't believe in magic.

Comment: So you *do* just have *one* `global $numTrax` *outside a function* and that's it? You are *not* passing the variable into the function when calling it? That's *not* very clear.

Comment: The problem is, you show us one function definition - `audioPlayer` - but then show us a separate function's invocation - `audioPlayList`.  We can't tell what's going on without seeing that function's definition, or how you've used `$numTrax` to that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said above, **never** use `global`.  It is exactly the wrong way to handle variables.

I'm guessing you want something like:

```
$numTrax = audioPlayer(5);

audioPlayList($user_id, $username, $numTrax);
```

Comment: Thanks. Yup, totally get all that - was trying to do it in one line is all. So somehow carrying the 5 from audioPlayer(5) to audioPlaylist()

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the variable in function like

```
global $numTrax;
```

to use the global variable. Otherwise, it will create a new variable with local scope.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to this:

```
function audioPlayer($newNumTrax)
{
    global $numTrax;

    echo ' ... all html ...';

    $numTrax = $newNumTrax;
}
```

To access or reassign a global variable within a function you need to use the `global` keyword to [bring it into scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). The function's argument should have a different name from the global variable so as not to get them confused. Then, just assign the value of the argument variable to the global variable.

Going by how you've called it, this function doesn't need to return anything. It just sets the value of the global variable.

For the `audioPlaylist` call, there's no reason to pass `$numTrax` as an argument. It's a global variable, so all functions can access it. Define the function like this:

```
function audioPlaylist($user_id, $username)
{
    global $numTrax;     #now you can use the global variable in this function

    #rest of function here
}
```

... and call it like this:

```
audioPlaylist($user_id, $username);
```

Please note that using `global` probably isn't a very good strategy for designing your program. I recommend passing variables to functions rather than relying on globals. If your functions get too unwieldy, break them into smaller functions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use same variable in your function

Try,

```
function audioPlayer($nT)
{
    echo ' ... all html ...';
    $numTrax = $nT;
    return $numTrax;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I don't guess wrong, I think you are using wrongly the keyword `global`.

The assign `$numTrax = $numTrax;` in

```
function audioPlayer($numTrax)
{
    $numTrax = $numTrax;
    return $numTrax;
}
```

is actually assigning the value of the **local** variable `$numTrax` to **itself**.

You have to define the **global var** just as:

```
$numTrax = null ;
```

and in your function you you must avoid **shadowing** the global one **renaming the parameter**, and **declare the global** variable (so no new local variable is created), like for example:

```
function audioPlayer($paramNumTrax)
{
    global $numTrax; // declare it exist a global var somewhere called $numTrax

    $numTrax = $paramNumTrax; // Asign the local value to the global variable
    return $paramNumTrax;
}
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

(in some cases could happen that: *"Using global keyword outside a function is not an error. It can be used if the file is included from inside a function."*. Don't know if this is your case)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Variables aren't global by default in PHP.  You have to declare them as such *in every function* where you want to use them, or set `$GLOBALS['numTrax']` instead.

With that said, though, it's generally considered a really bad idea to rely on global variables, for several reasons.  Most involve "action at a distance", or relying on implementation details that are now ten times harder to change rather than coding to an interface.  (The general prohibition is a bit overly broad, but globals aren't needed in 95%<sup>*</sup> of the cases where they're used.)

<sup>*</sup>(Totally made up number, cause i don't have stats on it with me.  But know that it's too high.  :P)